# Multiple videos playing at once Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a script that changes the play button on vimeo vids but it seems to activate all the videos on my site at the same time and not individually. I've added unique `player_id=video` `player_id=video1`, etc. You can see it live here (http://imdarrien.com/#modal2). Just click on a video and you can hear the audio play for all other videos I have.

https://jsfiddle.net/uxhxdcwp/5/

```
$(function () {
var iframe = document.getElementById('video');

var player = $f(iframe);

player.addEvent('ready', function () {
    player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
});

$('.playpause').click(function () {
    player.api('paused', function (paused) {
        if (!paused) {
            player.api('pause');
            $(".playpause").removeClass('pause');
        } else {
            player.api('play');
            $(".playpause").addClass('pause');
        }
    });
});

function onFinish(id) {
    $(".playpause").removeClass('pause');
}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're only taking action on the relevant video with selectors!

```
$('.playpause').click(function () {
   var el = $(this);
   var player = $f( $(this).siblings('iframe')[0] );
   player.api('paused', function (paused) {
      if (!paused) {
         player.api('pause');
         el.removeClass('pause');
      } else {
         player.api('play');
         el.addClass('pause');
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: I put that code in. http://imdarrien.com/#modal2  However, it does work but to play a video in the first place you need to click play a bunch of times.

Comment: Do you have the "pause" class on the ".playpause" element initially? I think that's the problem.

Comment: Wait sorry, I just looked at your website and how you've got everything set up. I changed my code to be more like your original- will you see if it works?